# Installing a tar.xz with a .BUILDINFO inside

Tags: linux, linux-mint, installation-package

I'm trying to install [Iceape](https://wiki.hyperbola.info/doku.php?id=en:project:iceape-uxp) from the Hyperbola distribution on my Linux Mint 19.2 installation.

They provide the distribution binary as a tar.xz file, on opening it I find a directory structure that includes /usr/bin, /usr/share and a few other locations. There are also files named .BUILDINFO, .PKGINFO and .MTREE. Simply extracting the files doesn't work, there are unresolved dependencies as indicated from the BUILDINFO.
Is this some kind of installation package similar to a deb or RPM, and how do I install it?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a direct link to the "binary package tar.xz".

Comment: Or you could find it *right there* on the project page that I linked to above.